# ¿Cómo adquirió "merienda" el significado de "joroba"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, definiciones, diferencias-regionales

Buscando una traducción para *"bentoo"* encontré en el DRAE que la palabra [**merienda**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=P0c4pKa) tiene una acepción totalmente desconocida para mi y para la que no encuentro una conexión razonable:

> 4. f. coloq. **Joroba, corcova, giba.**

¿Alguna idea de cómo adquirió ese significado? ¿Se utiliza habitualmente? ¿Hay diferencias regionales de uso?

Comment: Mirando en el [Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico de la lengua española](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) veo que se introdujo en 1790.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo único que encontré que podría estar relacionado señala que en Salamanca, España, el jueves en que comienza el carnaval es conocido como [*Jueves Merendero*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jueves_Lardero#Provincia_de_Salamanca). En ese día se solía ir a merendar al campo y los niños hacían la *corcova* o *corcoba*, que consistía en salir a pedir alimentos o dinero para preparar dicha merienda. Algunas referencias al respecto pueden hallarse en [el blog del pueblo salmantino de Escuernavacas](http://escuernavacas.blogspot.com.ar/2011/03/jueves-merendero-la-corcova.html), un artículo de la *Revista de Folklore* titulado ["Notas costumbristas sobre alimentación y gastronomía tradicionales en la provincia de Salamanca"](http://www.funjdiaz.net/folklore/07ficha.php?ID=360) y un [*Diccionario de términos lígrimos salmantinos*](http://www.manuelmateos.info/menu/libros/diccionario_charro.pdf) que dice que la corcoba era el

> Día en el cual los mozos iban a los caminos a pedir una contribución a
>   los viajeros

sin mayor especificación.

De ser correcta esta interpretación, el nexo saldría entre la *corcoba* (que es sinónimo de joroba) y la *merienda* para la cual se hacía. Lo que no me termina de cerrar es que parece ser un término excesivamente regional, limitado a Salamanca. Y también, supongo, cabe la posibilidad de que la relación fuera al revés.

Aparentemente, en [Chile y Perú se llama también "joroba" y "corcoba" a los dos días siguientes al cumpleaños](http://blog.derrama.org.pe/como-se-celebraban-los-cumpleanos-en-la-lima-de-antano/), en los que es de suponer que se consumirían toda clase de meriendas, pero tampoco puedo estar seguro de que haya relación. De todos modos, no deja de ser interesante que el único uso literario que encontré del término aparece en la obra de un poeta del Perú colonial, [Juan del Valle y Caviedes](https://books.google.com/books?id=5XY_Lej48OwC&pg=PA249#v=onepage&q=merienda&f=false) (un [estudio](https://books.google.com/books?id=MA4DuUaR3IQC&pg=PA267#v=onepage&q&f=false) indica que, en efecto, "merienda" se usa en el sentido de "joroba"):

> Su corcova revejida
>   la sustenta con la tienda
>   si para pasar la vida,
>   uno pone la merienda
>   y otro pone la comida.